# Free album art API for android?

Tags: android, albumart

I'm creating a music player for Android. In that I want to give the feature of downloading album arts for songs.

I'm looking for an API that provides images of sizes appropriate for android devices, so that they do not take much space.

Till now I've stumbled upon **Discogs** but they seems to lack in documentation.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discogs works fine. There are rate limits, but these aren't too low.

Also look at the combination of [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) and the [Cover Art Archive](http://coverartarchive.org/), which has been growing steadily (about 34% of MusicBrainz releases, at the time of writing, have got CAA artwork). This tends to be higher quality than Discogs' art.

Finally you can use Wikipedia via [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/About).